# How to visualize a multipart mime message saved into a file?

Tags: linux, email, mime-types

I am generating (with python) a multipart mail message, including some attachments, and saving it to a file: `message.mime`

Two questions:

- what is the correct extension to use for this kind of file? Is `.mime` correct?
- What tools can I use to visualize this file? I am not sending the file, just storing it in the filesystem, so a standard mail client will not do.

I am working on Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

> what is the correct extension to use for this kind of file? Is .mime correct?

The *most common* extension for an RFCx822 email message is `.eml`, probably followed by `.msg` in second place (although the latter is used for several different formats, including proprietary ones).

> What tools can I use to visualize this file? I am not sending the file, just storing it in the filesystem, so a standard mile client will not do.

Use a standard email client. If it can *save* email messages to a file, it should be able to open email messages from files that you generated as well. For example, both Thunderbird and Outlook Express are able to open any .eml file and show it as a message (verified experimentally).

---

Some clients (such as Mutt) won't recognize .eml files but can open ["mbox" format](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/mail-mbox-formats.html) mailboxes. The main difference between an .eml message and a .mbox file with 1 message in it is the `From_` header line above the message:

```
From foo@bar Tue Aug 20 09:14:16 2019

time.strftime("From {addr} %a %b %_d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

Additionally, messages inside a .mbox file should have a `Content-Length` header indicating the body size in bytes.

Comment: Thanks. Thunderbird requires me to configure a server in order to start working with it, which is inconvenient. I do not have credentials at hand to configure a server :(